# how to use awk command to filter values by columns when the column pattern is not clear

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a text file which looks like this

```
ab@cd.com      squid:uselessImportCheck     appname    2min  this is a random text    CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com      squid:uselessImportCheck     appname    7min  random text here         BUG
ab@cd.com      squid:uselessImportCheck     appname    2min  random                   VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com      squid:uselessImportCheck     appname    9min  text                     CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com      squid:uselessImportCheck     appname    3min  text random              BUG
```

I want to filter first and 6th column of this text, so the answer should looks like

```
ab@cd.com     CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com     BUG
ab@cd.com     VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com     CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com     BUG
```

I tried this with

```
awk '{print $1 $6}' filename.txt
```

But this does not work because even if the 5th column can be visually identified but because it has spaces and unpredictable random texts, the column number cannot be predicted. so the visually 6th column is not the actual 6th column when it gives to the awk command.

Can anyone help me to get the expected output.

Edit -- the text structure I have given here is not the actual one, I mean the required values are not in the first and the last column in the actual text. So I cannot use

```
awk '{print $1 $NF}'
```

I only showing this for demonstration

---

Here is a actual text for the reference.

```
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        2min        this is a random text        CODE_SMELL        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        7min        random text here        BUG        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        2min        random        VULNERABILITY        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        9min        text        CODE_SMELL        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        3min        text random        BUG        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
```

each main text field is separated by 8 spaces.

Comment: Perhaps `awk '{print $1 $NF}' filename.txt`

Comment: @jared_mamrot the text structure I have given here is not the actual one, I mean the required values are not in the first and the last column in the actual text. So I cannot use that

Comment: Since OP has given justification that OP doesn't want to print 1st and last field so reopened the dupe now.

Comment: @KasunWimaladarma, then kindly do mention logic by which you want to print the fields?

Comment: what is the column delimiter? a tab? multiple spaces? if multiple spaces ... will there always be at least 2 spaces between columns ... and will there never be multiple/consecutive spaces in a column value?

Comment: I want the column with email it is 4th column in the actual text. Then I need the colum with "CODE_SMELL","BUG","VULNERABILITY" that column. for that one column number cannot be predict because previous text has spaces in it @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @markp-fuso ----  it is 8 spaces

Comment: @KasunWimaladarma, please try to update your question with more suitable samples for better understanding of users/answerers, because if samples are in Good shape we can test solutions easily, cheers

Comment: the sample input does not have all columns separated by 8 spaces (sample input actually looks like fixed width); please confirm there are exactly 8 spaces between each column (and update the sample input to show this); otherwise let us know the minimum number of spaces between *every* column

Comment: your sample code suggests you know the column numbers in advance (eg, `$1` and `$6`); but one of your comments suggests you may be looking for specifically formatted strings (eg, email address) or specific strings (eg, `CODE_SMELL`); please update the question with more details on how you plan to determine which columns to print ... or will you know that in advance and your *only* issue is how to work with variable-width delimiters?

Comment: Please, post a proper sample data that portrays your actual data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks. Btw, not (yet) my downvote. Also, you could look into GNU awk's FIELDWIDTHS.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Question with updated with proper sample.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes I also think the only method to separately identify the column with "CODE_SMELL" & etc is the delimiter (8 spaces). Now I have updated the question with a accurate sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        2min        this is a random text        CODE_SMELL        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        7min        random text here        BUG        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        2min        random        VULNERABILITY        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        9min        text        CODE_SMELL        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
MAJOR        ab@cd.com        squid:uselessImportCheck        appname        3min        text random        BUG        "Unused import"        "Default-organization"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]]{2,}"}{print $2,$7}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ab@cd.com CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com BUG
ab@cd.com VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com BUG
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is 2 or more (`{2,}`) whitespace characters, then `print` 2nd and 7th field for each line. **Disclaimer**: this solution assume that there is never run of 2 or more whitespace inside 6th column. If you want to know more about `FS` then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: In my environment this gives nothing for the answer for same file.txt , What can be possible issue? version ?

Comment: @KasunWimaladarma what version of awk are you using (what is output when you do `awk --version`)?

Comment: @Daweo, it's sometimes useful, when giving a gawk-specific answer, to use `gawk '...'` instead of `awk`

Comment: @Daweo GNU awk 3.1.7

Comment: @KasunWimaladarma this is quite old, if possible try to upgrade it, if not try providing `FS` in less modern way `BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]*"}`

Answer (score 2):

As *each main text field is separated by 8 spaces*, use eight spaces as the field separator. For example, printing next to the last field, use:

```
$ awk -F'        ' '{print $(NF-1)}' file
```

Output:

```
"Unused import"
"Unused import"
"Unused import"
"Unused import"
"Unused import"
```

Tested with GNU awk, mawk, busybox awk and awk version 20121220. If using GNU awk, you could: `-F' {8}'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F' {8}' '{print $2,$7}' file
$ awk -F' {8}' '$0=$2" "$7' file
ab@cd.com CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com BUG
ab@cd.com VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com BUG
```

Answer (score 0):

if u don't care about loss of extra padding `(4 diff ways of achieving the same thing)` :

> ```
> gawk  '$_=$!_ FS$NF' 
>
> mawk  '($2=$NF)(NF=2)' 
>
> mawk2 '(_=$NF)($(NF=2)=_)'
>
> nawk  '$2=$NF substr(_,NF=2)'
> ```

```
ab@cd.com CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com BUG
ab@cd.com VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com BUG
```

if you want some extra padding but not identical :

> ```
> mawk '($2 = $NF) (NF = 2)' OFS='   '
> ```

```
ab@cd.com   CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com   BUG
ab@cd.com   VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com   CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com   BUG
```

but if u want exactly identical padding as original input :

> ```
> mawk '$!NF=substr($_,match($_,/^[ \t]*[^ \t]+[ \t]+/),RLENGTH) $NF'
> ```

```
ab@cd.com      CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com      BUG
ab@cd.com      VULNERABILITY
ab@cd.com      CODE_SMELL
ab@cd.com      BUG
```